# Android、splitを使うとエラーが出る

Tags: android, java

Android開発初心者です。
サイトのphpからの情報を分割して見やすく配置しようと思ったのですが、splitで分割出来ずエラーが出ます。

```
String[] strs = result.split("\n");
String dataInRes = "";
for (String elem: strs){
dataInRes += (elem.split(" => "))[1] + "\n";
}
TextView tv = (TextView) this.mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
tv.setText(dataInRes);
```

resultの中(サイトからの情報)

△△ => ○○
△△ => ○○
△△ => ○○
△△ => ○○
△△ => ○○

この○○の部分を一つづつ改行してdataInResに格納してTextViewに表示させたいのですが、

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

となり強制終了します。
解決方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

原因としては、 想定に反して " => " を含まない文字列が`elem`に設定されていることが考えられます。
LogCatに`elem`の内容を出力して確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
for (String elem: strs){
    Log.d("debug-output", elem);
    dataInRes += (elem.split(" => "))[1] + "\n";
}
```